# Multiple Key-Value pairs in a Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, hash

**EDIT:**

*In Short*

I have 3 attributes for a single entity, and I have about 100 such entities. I need a good data structure to store them and retrieve them efficiently.

*Example:*

Lets consider an image with 100 pixels.

Each pixel has three attributes - Red, Green and Blue. I need to store the entire image in terms of its pixels and its RGB values in a data structure like Hash.

An example data structure I was thinking of was something like this:

```
x={[:red => 1, :green => 2, :blue => 3],[:red => 21, :green => 21, :blue => 32], [:red => 21, :green => 21, :blue => 32]}
```

**My question:**

1) Is there a better way to store such sets of data?
2) Is there an efficient way to access such sets data?

In other words, What's the most easiest *and* efficient way to store multiple key-value pair **sets** of data and access them efficiently?

**Disclaimer:** I'm a newbie to Ruby (made some 50% progress).

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Where are you seeing that hash? There are syntax issues with it: a hash would look like `x = { 'red' => '1', 'green' => '2' }`. And hash keys are unique so as soon as you get to your second `'red'` key you've obliterated the first one.

Comment: Hashes have a key and a value.  Both the key and value are ruby objects.  if your key is a string, it's a string.  Also, there's something wrong with your hashes.  Are you actually copying what you are seeing on your screen, or retyping?

Comment: @Marc Talbot Hi, these are EXACTLY what I get as output from RMAGICK. I'm using the color_histogram which gives me this hash, incase that helps. Here's the link to the doc:

http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#color_histogram

Comment: @Tom L Thats one of the reasons why I chose to ask this question, this syntax is weird, but the code I have cited above works, and I'm able to retrieve its values. Anyway, thanks for the clarification!

Since my original hash is invalid, lets assume this - 
I want something like this:
x={[red=0,green=1,blue=3],[red=2,green=5,blue=2],[red=1,green=4,blue=3]}

What's the easiest way to recreate such a Hash of Arrays in Ruby (and also access it)? Any ideas?

Comment: color_histogram returns a hash where the keys are Pixel objects, and the values are numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're asking so please clarify if I'm off base. You want a quick and easy way to take a hash and turn it into a object with methods like `x.red`, correct? An OpenStruct might be the answer:

```
require 'ostruct'
hash = { :red => 1, :green => 2, :blue => 3 }
colorset = OpenStruct.new(hash)
```

Then you can call:

```
colorset.red + colorset.green + colorset.blue
```

And get:

```
=> 6
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your comments, forget the above, I think you simply need nested hashes with meaningful keys:

```
colors = { 'fuschia' => { 'red'=> 1 , 'green' => 2, 'blue' => 3 }, 
           'goldenrod' => { 'red'=> 2, 'green' => 3, 'blue'=> 4 } }
```

Then access values like this:

```
colors['fuschia']['red']
=> 1
```

Comment: Well, pretty close, but, I need to access something like:

hash={[:red => 1, :green => 2, :blue => 3],[:red => 21, :green => 21, :blue => 32], [:red => 21, :green => 21, :blue => 32]}

Thanks for your input!

Comment: In other words, (I leave this to you) How do you store multiple key-value pairs of data and access them efficiently? The Hash above is an example of what I'm trying to achieve. 

Edit: Just to be more clear - I have 3 attributes (Red , Green, Blue) for each pixel, and I have about 100 pixels.I need a good data structure to store them and retrieve them efficiently.
Thanks for your input!

Comment: @dsignr It does not get better than that :)